# Replace a period with HTML character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with some code. I put in an input and text in a paragraph is highlighted using `<mark>`. But when I add a period to highlight all the periods, the code freaks out and gives me the actual html code and has random highlights. So I tried to add a replacer to change the periods. Now it won't freak out but with won't highlight anything. Here is my code to try to replace the period with the html character number (`&#46;`):

```
var i = document.getElementById("Bar").value;
var inpu = $.trim(i);
var inp = inpu.replace(".", "&#46;");
var SearchReq = new RegExp("(\\b" + inp + "\\b)", "gim");
var Notes = document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML;
var after = Notes.replace(SearchReq, "<mark class=" + ColorOptionReady + ">$1</mark>");
document.getElementById("NoteHolder").innerHTML = after;
```

What is the problem with the code? (I tried removing the "\b" in the regex but that didn't fix it.)

Comment: When building your regex `SearchReq` you need to escape characters that have special meaning within a regex. So that includes periods, parentheses, square brackets, etc. Replacing them with html entities won't help, because the html of your paragraph element doesn't include html entities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `.` to `\\.` ( escape it, `\\` backslash required to keep backslash when you would pass string to RegExp) :

```
var inp = inpu.replace(".", "\\.");
```

Reason of your error is that `.` is character which has special meaning in RegExp, so you have to escape it prior passing to RefExp.

See [Special characters meaning in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) for more information.

**Good Luck )!**

Comment: You'd need to escape the backslash in the string literal, too. "\\."

Comment: @nnnnnn Why would I need "\\." instead of just "\."? Also, how would I do with for "\" since that escapes quotes and would mess up the replace?

Comment: It still messes up if I just type in "."

Comment: In a Javascript string literal, backslash is the escape character, so if you want an actual backslash in your string you have to escape it with another backslash. So the string literal `"\\."` creates a string that has one backslash followed by a dot (which is what you need for your regex). The string literal `"\."` creates a string that is just a dot - the backslash is ignored because it wasn't followed by an escape character.

Comment: @nnnnnn ohh, well i understand what you mean, thanks for use full suggestion.

Comment: That doesn't work? It gives me `word\.` and it doesn't highlight anything.